# How does GHCi print partially-applied values created from "pure"?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, applicative

I've been playing around with `Applicative` instances in order to figure out how they work. However, I honestly don't understand this behavior.

If I define my own datatype, then apply `pure` to it with no other arguments, nothing prints out, but it errors if I try to apply something to the result.

```
ghci> data T = A
ghci> pure A
ghci> pure A 0

<interactive>:21:1:
    No instance for (Show T) arising from a use of ‘print’
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

However, if I make `T` an instance of `Show`, then `A` is printed out in both cases.

```
ghci> data T = A deriving (Show)
ghci> pure A
A
ghci> pure A 0
A
```

What I really don't understand is how `pure A` can be a value that is printed differently between the two cases. Isn't `pure A` partially applied?

I do understand why calling `pure A 0` errors in the first example and doesn't in the second—that makes sense to me. That's using the `((->) r)` instance of `Applicative`, so it simply yields a function that always returns `A`.

But how is `pure` instantiated with only one value when the type of the applicative itself isn't yet known? Furthermore, how can GHC possibly print this value?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GHCi is a little bit peculiar. In particular, when you type an expression at the prompt, it tries to interpret it in two different ways, in order:

1. As an `IO` action to execute.
2. As a value to print out.

Since `IO` is `Applicative`, it is interpreting `pure A` as an `IO` action producing something of type `T`. It executes that action (which does nothing), and since the result is not in `Show`, it does not print anything out. If you make `T` an instance of `Show`, then it kindly prints out the result for you.

When you write `pure A 0`, GHCi sees this:

```
pure :: Applicative f => a -> f a
pure A :: Applicative f => f T
```

And since you apply `pure A` to `0`, `pure A` must be a function `a->b` for some types `a` and `b`, and `a` must contain `0`.

```
(Num a, Applicative f) => f T ~ (a -> b)
```

(Note that `x ~ y` means that `x` and `y` unify—they can be made to have the same type.)

Thus we must have `f ~ ((->) a)` and `T ~ b`, so in fact GHC infers that, in this context,

```
pure A :: Num a => ((->) a) T
```

Which we can rewrite as

```
pure A :: Num a => a -> T
```

Well, `(->) a` is an instance of `Applicative`, namely "reader", so this is okay. When we apply `pure A` to `0` we get something of type `T`, namely `A`. This *cannot* be interpreted as an `IO` action, of course, so if `T` is not an instance of `Show`, GHCi will complain.

Answer (score 7):

When you give a value of ambiguous type to the GHCi prompt to evaluate, it tries to default the type in various ways.  In particular, it tries whether it can fit an `IO a` type, in case you want to execute an IO action (see [the GHC manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#actions-at-prompt)).  In your case, `pure A` defaults to the type `IO T`.  Also:

> Furthermore, GHCi will print the result of the I/O action if (and only if):
>
> - The result type is an instance of `Show`.
> - The result type is not `()`.

Comment: Why specially `IO`? Is that just an arbitrary default?

Comment: @AlexisKing, it is a convenient default for the sort of interactive development people tend to do with GHCi. There is no `main` in GHCi, and it would be annoying to have to invoke some  special interpreter command to execute an `IO` action.

Comment: With `IO` actions and only `IO` actions, it *executes* them as well as evaluating, so they need to be treated specially. That it also defaults generic `Applicative/Monad` actions to it is probably just a nice side effect, although one that is explicitly mentioned in the manual.

Comment: @dfeuer Ooh, I see, that makes sense. It assumes IO because it needs to in order for interactive evaluations that yield IO to be executed.