# Understanding how the pure function is resolved in Haskell

Tags: haskell, ghci, applicative

In GHCi when I type `pure 2` it returns `2`; or `pure "aa"` returns `"aa"`. I wonder how this applicative instance is resolved for 2 or "aa" by GHCi.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28979021/3608068

Comment: thank you @user3608068. The link you provided exactly answers my question but I was not able to find it when I searched for it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHCi performs some magic to be user-friendly.

When entering an expression whose type is of the form `... => f a`, it tries to instantiate `f` to `IO`. In your case, this is possible since `IO` is an applicative (and a monad).

Secondly, when an expression having a type of the form `... => IO a` is entered, it is run as an IO action.

Finally, if `a` is of class `Show`, the result is printed. In your case `"aa"` is the result (and the type `a` is `String`), so GHCi prints that.

Comment: Thank you Mr chi, I feel enlightened now :)